# OpenShift WebSocket drop to xhr-polling no websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, openshift

I'm quite sure it was working some week ago.
But since a few days xhr-polling is everything I get.

It is working fine with websockects connection on my local machine, but not in Openshift.

I if I asked my Openshift server about transport it only gives me back: ["htmlfile", "xhr-polling", "jsonp-polling"] and If I force it to use websockets it fails.

This is the url format I am using on client:
 var socket = io.connect('ws://mysite-myuser.rhcloud.com:8000');

and loading the website on browser as:http://mysite-myuser.rhcloud.com

My server is node with socket.io, and work fine in local using websocket as transport.

Did something change? or Shall I change something to get again socket as transport?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an open issue for this (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1070317) and we are working on a hotfix release for it.  Please check the bugzilla referenced here and watch for it to be closed when the fix is implemented.